# GEKKO NL solver failed with initial guess of 0

Tags: non-linear-regression, gekko

I'm new to GEKKO and test it with a simple non linear optimization problem, but it fires an error exception of "Solution Not Found" when initial guess is 0.
I have two issues with it:

(1) Why ?

(2) How can I know which initial guess is ok for the solver?

My code was written according to the Nonlinear Regression example given here: https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/blob/master/docs/examples.rst

Measure points file can be downloaded from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ai5vbd2u5gx8r17/measure.npy?dl=0

```
# Model:
#            x
# y = -------------
#      1- (a1*x)^2
#
# Finding a1 for fitting model as much as possible for the given measures points


# loading given measure points (file exist at https://www.dropbox.com/s/ai5vbd2u5gx8r17/measure.npy?dl=0)
measure_data = np.load("C:/measure.npy")
xm = measure_data[0]
ym = measure_data[1]

# GEKKO model
m = GEKKO()

# parameters
x = m.Param(value=xm)
a = [m.FV(value=0.000) for i in range(1)]
for par in a:
    par.STATUS=1

# variables
y = m.CV(value=ym)
y.FSTATUS=1

m.Equation(y==x/(1-(a[0]*x)**2))
    
# regression mode
m.options.IMODE = 2

# optimize
m.solve(disp=False)


p = [par.value[0] for par in a] 
optimized_y = xm/(1-(p[0]*xm)**2)

plt.figure(1)

plt.plot(xm,ym,'k', label = "measurements")
plt.plot(xm,optimized_y,'r', label = "optimized_y")

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

The solver gives a solution if I set the initial guess to 0.001, but it was just playing with value with no real understanding what i'm doing.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An initial guess of `0` shouldn't be a problem, but it depends on how the solver searches for the solution and the data. If the solver iterates to `a[0]*x==1` then it could result in divide-by-zero.

```py
m.Equation(y==x/(1-(a[0]*x)**2))
```

Try reformulating the equation as:

```py
m.Equation(y*(1-(a[0]*x)**2)==x)
```

If the equation can't be rearranged to avoid the singularity, another thing to try is setting a constraint `z>=1e-5` to avoid divide-by zero such as:

```py
z = m.Var(lb=1e-5)
m.Equation(z==(1-(a[0]*x)**2))
m.Equation(y==x/z)
```

For future questions, please post a complete problem with sample that reproduces the issue and can be tested. This question is missing `measure.npy`.

Comment: Thanks. I tried both suggested methods: reformulating, and constraint. The behavior is the same, for initial guess of value of 0.000 I get "Solution Not Found", for 0.001 there is a solution.  I added a link to the measures data file so it can be tested.

Comment: I checked another suggestion of yours which succeeded -  reducing non linearity as given in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73294144/gekko-nl-solver-gives-fitting-values-that-are-not-corresponding-to-the-found-par.  
In this case, I could leave the denominator and use the form m.Equation(y==x/(1-a[0]*(x**2))),  and then calculate the original value of a[0] after solution. But why the other suggestions you gave here above do not work? I'm trying to understand how to use the GEKKO and hope it will light some more considerations.

Comment: I used SOLVER =1 as you suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73294144/gekko-nl-solver-gives-fitting-values-that-are-not-corresponding-to-the-reference
Everything works well. I can use the form m.Equation( y==x/(1-(a[0]*x)**2) ) , I can initializing with 0.000 and get some solution (not the best, but a solution), and for 0.001 it converses as shown in the graph.

Comment: Thanks for posting a solution. It appears that the problem was that IPOPT just couldn’t find a solution. Here is more information on Interior Point methods: https://apmonitor.com/me575/index.php/Main/InteriorPointMethod