# GEKKO NL Solver gives fitting values that are not corresponding to the reference values

Tags: non-linear-regression, gekko

I'm trying to find the parameters values for best fitting of the follow model function with a given set of points.

```
Model:
                 x
  y = ------------------------
       1- (a1*x)^2 + (a2*x)^4

where parameters are:  a1, a2
```

(1) I used the found optimized parameters values with this equation but it gives around y=~0 for any x (red graph).

[image]

(3) Surprisingly, using a model with only one parameter as follow gives much better fitting.

```
Model:
            x
  y = -------------
       1- (a1*x)^2

where parameters are:  a1
```

[image]

Here is my code (I followed the code for non linear regression as shown here: https://github.com/BYU-PRISM/GEKKO/blob/master/docs/examples.rst)

Note: I played with initial values until got one where the solver didn't fire exception of "Non Solution Found". The values I used are 0.3 for each parameter (I have no idea why this is a good value if at all)

Measure points file can be downloaded from here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ai5vbd2u5gx8r17/measure.npy?dl=0

```
import numpy as np
import math
import os.path

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from gekko import GEKKO

# Model:
#                x
# y = ------------------------
#      1- (a1*x)^2 + (a2*x)^4
#

# measured data (file exist at https://www.dropbox.com/s/ai5vbd2u5gx8r17/measure.npy?dl=0)
measure_data = np.load("C:/measure.npy")
xm = measure_data[0]
ym = measure_data[1]

# GEKKO model
m = GEKKO()

# parameters
x = m.Param(value=xm)
a = [m.FV(value=0.3) for i in range(2)]
for par in a:
    par.STATUS=1

# variables
y = m.CV(value=ym)
y.FSTATUS=1

m.Equation( y==x/(1-(a[0]*x)**2+(a[1]*x)**4) )
    
# regression mode
m.options.IMODE = 2

# optimize
m.solve(disp=False)


p = [par.value[0] for par in a] 
optimized_y = xm/(1-(p[0]*xm)**2+(p[1]*xm)**4)


plt.figure(1)

plt.plot(xm,ym,'k', label = "measurements")
plt.plot(xm,optimized_y,'r', label = "optimized_y")

plt.xlabel('x')
plt.ylabel('y')
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the suggestions from [GEKKO NL solver failed with initial guess of 0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73293270/gekko-nl-solver-failed-with-initial-guess-of-0), try rearranging the equation to avoid divide-by-zero. An intermediate variable definition (`z`) can help simplify the expression.

```py
z = m.Intermediate(1-(a[0]*x)**2)
m.Equation(y*z==x + z*(a[1]*x)**4)
```

Another thing that can help is to define the parameters to reduce the nonlinearity of the problem:

```py
z = m.Intermediate(1-b[0]*(x**2))
m.Equation(y*z==x + b[1]*z*(x**4))
```

After the problem finishes solving, compute the original values of the `a` parameters as `a[0]=math.sqrt(b[0].value[0])` and `a[1]=(b[1].value[0])**(1/4)`.

It may also be helpful to try a different solver such as `m.options.SOLVER=1` (APOPT solver). Nonlinear optimization problems sometimes need a good initial guess or bounds, especially when there are terms such as power of 4. For future questions, please post sample data that reproduces the problem.

Comment: Thank you very much! Changing to SOLVER=1 made it all (with SOLVER=2 no method was working , mostly exit with No solution Found).  When SOLVER=1 I could set different initial values and it converges into meaningful results, sometimes better, sometimes less , but good in overall.  Using parameters out of the power for reducing nonlinearity is great idea, but specifically in thigs case it allows the solver to reach a solution with minus values for b[1] which can not be used for a[1], as we do not use complex space.  But it is a really great tip that can be used in other cases.

Comment: Note: I had fix the question, as the correct equation for the model is m.Equation( y==x/(1-(a[0]*x)**2+(a[1]*x)**4) )

Comment: Thanks for posting the solution and the correction. Using the b parameters may still be possible if you set the lower bound to zero with b=m.Array(m.FV,2,value=0.3,lb=0)